# Unit testing directives without unnecessary dependencies in module AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I want to write a test for the directive.

**In App**

```js
requiresDependencies = ["someModule1","someModule2"];
var app = angular.module('app', requiresDependencies);
```

**In test**

```js
describe("Logon Hours Editor", function ()
{
    var compile, rootScope;
    var element;

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(['$compile', '$rootScope', function ($compile, $rootScope)
    {
        compile = $compile;
        rootScope = $rootScope;
        element = $compile('some html')($rootScope);
    } ]
    )); ....
```

My directive is relative to the main unit, and I do not want to connect other test modules (someModule1,someModule2) described in *"requiresDependencies"* ,because later their numbers and names can be changed.
How do I connect only without his dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock them. For example, you can create a module called `mocks` with a d with the services or directives you want to mock. You then load it with `beforeEach(module('mocks'));` and your calls from the test suite to whatever service you have in `mocks` will be using the dummy implementation.

You can put this mock module in your test folder, like `/test/lib/my-mocks.js` (next to angular-mocks.js, if you're using angular-seed). Lastly, you include it in `karma.conf.js`:

```
files = [
  'app/lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js',
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'test/lib/jasmine-jquery.js',
  'app/lib/angular/angular.js',
  ...
  'test/lib/myproject/my-mocks.js',
   ...
];
```

Another approach is using jasmine spies. For example:

```js
 spyOn($location, 'absUrl').andCallFake(function (p) {
     return 'http://localhost/app/index.html#/this/is/my/route';
 });
```

Comment: Is it possible to create such mocks without creating additional files?

Comment: I guess you can, provided that you declare them in a file that karma can see (listed in karma.conf.js). in any case, I'd say that mocked modules should be in a separate file because you don't want them in your app and the goal is to avoid repeating yourself. mocked modules are declared just like regular modules, but you can name them like "myapp.mocks.mymodule" for the sake of clarity

Comment: @b1r3k maybe this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680105/how-do-i-provide-re-usable-sample-data-values-to-my-angularjs-jasmine-unit-tes/19682501#19682501